# Looking for a word processor with the power of Markdown

Tags: text-editor, word-processor, markdown

Basically, I am looking for a word editor (like Word or Pages) that is compatible with Markdown. I want to be able to write in Markdown but with the concept of pages. Their are a lot of Markdown editor but none that handles the concept of pages (I know that Markdown is primary for the web, so I understand why), but I will use Markdown for document that I will need to print, so I need to know, in advance, the number of pages.

Here is what I need:

1. compatible with Markdown
2. header : same for every page
3. footer : same for every page
4. number of pages and page numbers
5. automatically numbering headings ([you can do it with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/PfcX2/1/))
6. editable stylesheet
7. live preview
8. easy to use

[Mou](http://mouapp.com/) can do must of this (items 1, 5, 6, 7, 8). The problems are for header, footer and number of pages and page numbers

Do you know a software that can do what I need ?

Comment: It's not so much that Markdown is for the web, it's that it is for plain text and text editors. You won't find many word processors that allow markdown because it's unnecessary. They can already do what markdown adds to text.

Comment: I recommend you to learn LaTeX. Of course, the syntax is different from markdown. But after trying a lot of editors (MSWord, Pages, OpenOffice/LibreOffice), I can tell it is the best one and you can do all you want (from items 2 to 8, 7 is done by opening generated document in Preview). Spend 2 or 3 days learning it, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

[Texts](http://www.texts.io/) is a strange hybrid between a text editor and what you are looking for.

[image]

- Markdown visual editor

> Write using Markdown - without having to remember the markup. With
>   Texts you can apply styles to words or paragraphs and immediately see
>   the results. Your images and tables are displayed directly within
>   Texts.

- Well-structured content

> Use Texts to create structured documents. You set your titles and
>   headings, and they will stay in place if you export your document to
>   another format.

- Blogging on GitHub Pages

> Content written in Texts can be easily published as a blog on GitHub
>   Pages, with math, tables, footnotes etc.

- Perfect for academics

> Developed to cover all your needs: formulas and footnotes,
>   bibliography and citations, tables and links.

- Single source publishing

> Writing your documents in Texts gives you a lot of flexibility. You
>   can easily convert your words into clean HTML5, professional PDFs,
>   ePub or Word format, or even a presentation.

- Professional typesetting

> Texts produces immaculate PDFs. Everything you create — from
>   paragraphs of text to mathematical formulae — is perfectly typeset.
>   See some sample documents.

- Cross-platform application

> Mac OS X or Windows? Doesn't matter, use Texts on both. The app has
>   native look and feel on each platform, and the document format is
>   common across platforms.

- Custom themes

> Change the appearance of your text editor with themes.

- Export templates

> Adjust style of any published documents with export templates.

http://www.texts.io/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Answers should be more than just links; they should explain why they're correct and how the answer addresses the questioner's problem.